# Python PyCharm Plot View

Tags: python, matplotlib, pycharm, seaborn

This is a Python-specific PyCharm IDE question regarding the viewing of resulting output plots (in this case, from the Seaborn library). I am looking for a more user-friendly form of displaying my plots external to creating a new window (then exiting that window and opening the next window...) every time I want to view my output plots. In this case, I would also like to avoid any sort of web-dependent output. An example of the incredibly ugly and down-right brutal way in which I currently generate then view plots is as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
## plot plot plot
plt.show()
```

I also put myself through this in other viz libraries such as matplotlib. While I am aware of the sequential output formatting of Jupyter NoteBooks, I prefer working through PyCharm's environment and would like any answers to be geared toward the PyCharm IDE. Any and all suggestions are certainly welcome. Ideally, I will be provided the most sufficient way to view my plots across any library, but library-specific answers are absolutely welcome as well.

Comment: seaborn plots are matplotlib plots, so I'm going to switch the tags

Comment: what do you mean by brutal?

Comment: specifically, it looks like you might get what you want by doing `plt.show(block=False)`.  Note, if you want fine control over your plot windows, run your own GUI.  I use PyQt and it works great at opening and controlling as many matplotlib windows as I want.  I think this simpler method is what you're asking for, though.